# Nested IF/AND Statement with picklist value field. Error: Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Tags: reporting, formula-field, report-formula

I am trying to create an nested IF AND conditional statement to look at case severity and time (hrs) it took to reach a certain case status. I have tried the below but keep getting the error

"Warning
Error when encoding row-level formula: Field Case.b1_case_severity__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions."

From what I have searched I may need to use `CONTAINS(TEXT(` but don't know where I would apply it in the formula.

```
IF(
AND(Case.b1_case_severity__c, "1 - Critical",
Case.Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 9.5),1,
IF(
AND(b1_case_severity__c, "2 - High",
Case.Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 9.5),1,
IF(
AND(b1_case_severity__c, "3 - Medium",
Case.Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 19),1,
IF(
AND(b1_case_severity__c, "4 - Low",
Case.Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 28.5),1,0))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Most of the  questions here are pretty Apex and JavaScript centric. You might get a faster response on the Trail Blazer forums where there is more of an Admin focus.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson We handle all aspects of Salesforce and many Salesforce-related products. It just so happens that *most* of the questions are about code, but we handle formulas, validation rules, reports, and anything else that is is in Salesforce (though, notoriously, we rarely handle [tag:unit-test], because they're usually low quality).

Comment: Ohh for sure, I just thought he might get a faster response on a different forum. My intent was only to be helpful, not mislead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check a picklist value, use ISPICKVAL, as in `ISPICKVAL(b1_case_severity__c, "1 - High")`. However, you can be more efficient here by using CASE:

```
IF(Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 
    CASE(b1_case_severity__c, 
        "1 - Critical", 9.5, 
        "2 - High", 9.5, 
        "3 - Medium", 19, 
        "4 - Low", 28.5, 0),
    1,
    0
)
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much!